# TFDConnection is not establishing connection to Microstoft Access Database(mdb)

Tags: c++, ms-access, database-connection, c++builder

I am trying to connect to an Access DB in the local drive using TFDConnection. But My code is getting stuck or hanged while trying to open the connection. Please find the code snippet below:

```
         CreateBOTSchema(AnsiString accesslocation){
    AnsiString db;
    db = "Database=" + accesslocation;
    FDConnection1->Params->Clear();
    FDConnection1->DriverName="MSAcc";
    FDConnection1->Params->Add(db);
    FDConnection1->Connected=true;
FDQuery1->Connection=FDConnection1;
    FDQuery1->SQL->Clear() ;
    FDQuery1->SQL->Add("CREATE TABLE COMPONENTS ");
    FDQuery1->SQL->Add("(ELEMID TEXT(50),");
    FDQuery1->SQL->Add("UGL_SORT TEXT(50),");
    FDQuery1->SQL->Add("STOCK_NO TEXT(50),");
    FDQuery1->SQL->Add("QUANTITY double,");
    FDQuery1->SQL->Add("DIAMETER double,");
    FDQuery1->SQL->Add("DESCRIPTION TEXT(100),");
    FDQuery1->SQL->Add("PRICE double,");
    FDQuery1->SQL->Add("LENGTH double)");
    try {
         
       FDQuery1->ExecSQL();
        
    } catch (...) {
        ShowMessage("Error creating BOT.mdb. Please close the database. ");
        
    }
}
```

I am calling this method from another location: CreateBOTSchema("C:\BOT\db.mdb"); This method is getting stuck at "FDConnection1->Connected=true;" line. Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: What does 'getting stuck' mean - what is error message?

Comment: TFD connection? You have to explain that . You do NOT connect to a text file, or a word file or a access file. You OPEN such files. MASSVIE different use of terms here. Access is a file system  - you can only open such files - you never really connect to a plane jane file sitting on disk. As a result, the path name in that connection has to be a full legal path name to the file. You are thus using the windows file system, and this is why you can't use say sky-drive or other systems - they are http based, and often a connection to say MySQL is a socket/IP based conneciton. Access is a file.

Comment: 'getting stuck' means it will not go to the next line. It will wait in that line of code. After some time the application is getting crashed.

Comment: TFDConnection is a Embarcadero RAD Studio API class. Please see the link below.
 http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/FireDAC.Comp.Client.TFDConnection

Comment: No debugging info, some error message? http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Defining_Connection_(FireDAC)

Comment: I dont have any error message. It simply hanging at line "FDConnection1->Connected=true;". I have followed all the things mentioned in that link.

Comment: It's much easier to build up your connection at design time and get it all working. Then, if your requirements are such that you can't use the design time connection you can at least cut and paste the properties across to your run time code. A typical MS Access connection as well as the full path to the *.mdb main database file will include the following:

Comment: ;DriverId=281;MaxBufferSize=2048;MaxScanRows=8;PageTimeout=5;SafeTransactions=0;Threads=3;UserCommitSync=Yes

Comment: At design time: put a new FDConnection component on your form. Right click on it and select "Connection editor". Select the "driver ID" as MSAccThen click on the "Wizard" button and run through the new conneciton.

Comment: It is working fine from designer. But when i access it from code is not working. Also I am trying to capture the exception which is also not working: try {
    FDConnection1->Connected=true;
 } catch (Exception *Ex) {
  ShowMessage("Error creating FDConnection1"+Ex->ToString());
 } Exception is not catching in catch block.

Comment: If it works fine at design time hen you must have one (or more) properties in your run time set up of FDConnection1 different to those as per your design.time settings.

Comment: It is working only while debugging. I am now trying to find the issue while deploying and running it. I am getting an error in catch block, but not able to find the type or message of that exception.catch(...)
 {
  // catch any other errors (that we have no information about)
  ShowMessage("Error creating FDConnection1");
 }